# Issues mounting a RAID5 in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, raid-5

I've been trying to access the contents on a RAID5 for the past 2 days.
Although it looks like the information is there when getting the array details, it doesn't show any files when mounted.

I first assemble the RAID:

```
root@ubuntu:/# mdadm --assemble /dev/md127
```

And run:

```
root@ubuntu:/# mdadm -D /dev/md127
```

This is the result for the command above:

```
/dev/md127:
    Version : 1.2
Creation Time : Tue May 16 12:47:50 2017
 Raid Level : raid5
 Array Size : 8775916032 (8369.37 GiB 8986.54 GB)
Used Dev Size : 2925305344 (2789.79 GiB 2995.51 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
Total Devices : 4
Persistence : Superblock is persistent
Intent Bitmap : Internal

Update Time : Wed May 17 11:55:37 2017
      State : clean
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

     Layout : left-symmetric
 Chunk Size : 512K

       Name : ubuntu:127  (local to host ubuntu)
       UUID : 43de9318:faf37e33:ad6f7388:025ad6fa
     Events : 4614

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8        5        0      active sync   /dev/sda5
   1       8       21        1      active sync   /dev/sdb5
   2       8       37        2      active sync   /dev/sdc5
   4       8       53        3      active sync   /dev/sdd5
```

I hope you can help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just creates the raid array into a device, it doesn't actually mount it.

Once you've done the above, you need to mount the device `/dev/md127` to a mount point

Presuming `/dev/mount/test` exists:

`mount /dev/md127 /dev/mount/test`

Then the files will be listed under this directory:

```
ls /dev/mount/test/
files
more files
lots of files
etc
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've just created the directory test in /dev/mount/ and after running the following commands I'm still not getting any files at all. root@ubuntu:/# mount /dev/md127 /dev/mount/test
root@ubuntu:/# ls /dev/mount/test
root@ubuntu:/#

Comment: So there's no error given? just no files shown? -- are you sure that you've actually put any files there?

Comment: No error at all. I'm just concerned I've accidentally deleted all the files on the RAID. But in that case, why would it show nearly 3Gb in 'Used Dev Size'?

Comment: I'm unsure where you're seeing that stat, but if it' shows no files with ls, as root, I very much doubt there's much there. Try ls -la to make sure. Remember that the raid itself takes up some space for file information etc.